# Odd behavior trying to install Windows 11 on a laptop

Tags: laptop, windows-11, linux-mint, windows-installer, setup

So here is some background information. I was using a laptop with Linux on it. I got a new gaming laptop so I was going to install Windows on the laptop that had Linux on it and let my wife use it as its much faster than the one she currently uses.

Somehow I must have borked the hard drive - at least I thought I did, that had Linux on it, as the Windows 11 setup did not recognize the hard drive and I could no longer boot to the Linux OS anymore either. So I bought an adapter to plug the old Linux HD into my Windows laptop and was able to successfully delete the partitions and reformat it. My Windows laptop was able to see that hard drive without issue.

So I put the drive back into my old one and Windows 11 setup still doesnt see the drive even though my new laptop sees it without issue. Using `shift + F10` does not open the command prompt in the Windows setup. Any ideas on what might be going on? Its odd that my Windows laptop has no problems detecting the drive at all.

Comment: Try installing Windows 10.  The laptop may not be certified for Windows 11.

Comment: I can give that a try, it does have Intel Core i7 however.

Comment: The CPU needs to be a Generation 8 or 9 or newer. I have a Core i7 that will not run Windows 11 Production

Comment: Good to know, I just downloaded the Windows 10 Media Creation Tool I'll give that a try. Knowing this I think Its likely to work.

Comment: Still having the same problem. Getting to where you choose where to install windows no drives are listed.

Comment: I am not certain what is happening. Windows 10 (and 11) get drivers from the Microsoft Driver Catalog so there may be some issue with the drive (beyond just identifying it).

Comment: Maybe use FDISK to remove all partitions, format the drive, and then try again

Comment: When going from Linux to Windows, I use DiskPart to clean the disk and then create the basic partition, and then the OS installer can pick it up. Sometimes this requires running DiskPart a couple times in a row.

Comment: I did drop partitions once with Disk Management in Windows, I'll try drop partitions and format a few more times to see if that helps.

Comment: The file system of the USB drive containing the Windows install doesnt matter does it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it fixed it was a BIOS problem. I found this and step 3 mentioned

> Ensure that the SATA mode is set correctly (AHCI is recommended for most systems).

Sure enough it was set to SCSI and not AHCI. Windows is now installed. I did have to drop the partition again in setup because it was still detecting the Linux filesystem.

https://www.auslogics.com/en/articles/hdd-not-detected-during-windows-installation/#3-adjust-biosuefi-settings